# No Style/CSS on initial load with SvelteKit and adapter-static

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I created a little page with [sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) and [tailwind css](https://tailwindcss.com/). Now I want to use the [sveltejsadapter-static](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static) to create a complete static html version. This works fine for all subpages like `/imprint` or `/privacy` but the the first page `/` doesn't load the stylesheet.

Here's my svelte.config.js

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false
        }),
        trailingSlash: 'always',
        prerender: {
            default: true
        }
    },
};

export default config;
```

By browsing to `/imprint` all styles look fine. The link to the stylesheet starts with `/_app/…`

When I load the base url, I can see the correct styles flashing for some milliseconds, but after that, all styles are gone. If I remove the `/` of the style and js links in the source code (`_app/…`), the page looks fine. But I can't find an option to create the first index file without the staring slash.

Also strange: When I click on the logo from `/imprint` (which links to `/`), the page looks fine, but never on first load.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

I defined the html tag in a `component` which is already defined in the `app.html`.

```
<svelte:head>
  <html lang="de" />
</svelte:head>
```

Comment: Can you explain this more  please? I'm having the same issue. But I don't quite understand your solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems no one answers this, I'll just draft my experience and solution for this.

If you're using adapter-static + ssr + prerender, you can use onMount() or detect if loaded in browser before rendering the slot, this should solve the initial rendering.

```
// inside your +layout.svelte
<script>
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
</script>

{#if browser}
    <slot />
{/if}
```

Comment: Would requiring JS to render the site half defeat the purpose of SSR by negatively impacting SEO?